# Does TDengine support timestamp by nanosecond?

Tags: database, tdengine

Does TDengine support timestamp by nanosecond ? What should I do if I want to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the timestamp precision when you create the DB, for example:

> create database db precision 'ns';